# not use "using" statement for TransactionScope

Tags: c#

i always using the following format to use transactionscope.

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()){
  ....
}
```

sometimes i want to wrap the transactionscope to a new class, for example DbContext class, i want to using the statement like

```
dbContext.Begin();
...
dbContext.Submit();
```

it seems the transactioncope class need use "using"statement to do dispose, i want to know if there is anyway not use "using".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can design your `DbContext` class as follows:

```
public sealed class DbContext : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed;
    private TransactionScope scope;

    public void Begin()
    {
        if (this.disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException();
        this.scope = new TransactionScope();
    }

    void Submit()
    {
        if (this.disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException();
        if (this.scope == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        this.scope.Complete();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.scope != null)
        {
            this.scope.Dispose();
            this.scope = null;
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }
}
```

and you can use it as follows:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    context.Begin();

    // Operations.

    context.Submit();
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    …
}
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
var scope = new TransactionScope();
try
{
    …
}
finally
{
    scope?.Dispose();
}
```

(i.e. you can only use the `using` statement with types that implement the `IDisposable` interface.)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a try..finally and call Dispose by yourself, but it's not as clear as the using form.